# JDK version 1.8 in the system but JDK 11 on VScode

Tags: java, macos, visual-studio-code, java-8

I have JDK11 and JADK8 both installed on my MacOS. I have changed the JDK default version to 1.8 to make sure GlassFish V5 can be run.

However, the change is not taken place at VSCode, and VSCode terminal keeps on showing JDK11 as JAVA version, which is preventing me from running GlassFish server though VSCode.

[image]
[image]

How can I fix this?
Thank you

Comment: Restart vscode.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I did, unfortunately it's still the same. I'll try restarting my machine.

Comment: Use the absolute path to java 1.8 binary if you're not able to edit the PATH variable in the vscode terminal

Comment: If Terminal has the correct version of Java, try to start VSCode from an instance of Terminal. Good idea to set JAVA_HOME too in ~/.bashrc. If it's already set, it might be set to the wrong path

Answer (score 0):

Here you can choose wich version to install.

[image]

*Edit :* as mentionned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56859959/how-to-find-and-change-java-compiler-option-in-visual-studio-code)

> VS Code does not have built-in support for Java projects. You need to install some Java extensions and configure them to specify the correct Java JDK version, which you can do by either setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable or by setting the java.home setting:

Comment: Isn't that for installing another version of the extension?

Comment: Yes that's installing another version of the extension. not what i'm looking for.

Comment: Have you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56859959/how-to-find-and-change-java-compiler-option-in-visual-studio-code

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the value of `JAVA_HOME` environment variable. Check your `JAVA_HOME` path in the settings.json file.

[image]

If it shows Java11, set `JAVA_HOME` environment variable as per your requirement and restart VSCode. Check [How to set JAVA_HOME in Mac permanently?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14702702/10819573).

Comment: This worked but it gives the following message `Java 11 or more recent is required to run the Java extension.(Current JDK: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-8.jdk/Contents/Home)`

Anyway to solve that?

Comment: Great! Now, you need [Is it possible to select JDK 8 for Java project in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63770624/10819573) and/or [JDK 1.8 not supported by vs code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56307730/10819573).

Answer (score 0):

Java extension needs jdk11 or recent version to support, so it's required to set **jdk11** as `java.home` in vscode, but it's also achievable to specify other jdk version for project.

Open Command Palette and Search **Java: Configure Java Runtime**.

> Choose JDK8 for **Project JDKs**.
> Choose JDK11 or recent version as
> **Java Tooling Time.**

Don't forget to **reload window** to make the change effective.

[image]

Detailed information please view official docs: [Configure JDK](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_configure-jdk)